# Stop recursion when variable is reached

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have a prolog program with searches for something and every time it hasn't found it, it increments a variable by 1. If it never finds what the user is searching for, it will search forever. Can I stop prolog from doing that, if a special variable is reached? This is the predicate which searches for something:

```
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
% find(X,Y,N) :- ...search for it
% find(X,Y,N) :- ...if not found, increment N by 1 and repeat recursion
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
find(Y,I,G) :- member(Y,I), G is 0.
find(Y,I,G) :- not(member(Y,I)), expand(I,O), find(Y,O,G1), G is G1+1.
find(Y,I,50) :- fail.
```

So I want to write something like

```
find(X,Y,50) :- return false
```

So that the program returns false, if it hasn't found it after 50 recursions.
How do I realize that?

EDIT: This is my code: http://pastebin.com/4X7BSFQ2

`vwg(X,Y,G)` is searching if the two persons X and Y are related with grade G
for example:

```
vwg(vanessaMueller, selinaMueller, 1)
```

is true, cause vanessaMueller is her mother

Comment: find(X,Y,N) :- N < 50, ...

Comment: This doens't stop the recursion for my code. I have linked my complete code, when I run something like `vwg(notExistentPerson1, notExistentPerson2, X).` and add the `N < 50` the program should stop if 50 is reached but it doesn't somehow. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have the third argument (the iteration count) bound, you can simply count down. Once you hit zero, you've failed:

```
find( Y , I , G ) :-  %
  integer(G) ,        % enforce the contract that G must be bound
  G > 0 ,             % if we've not yet hit zero,
  member(Y,I) ,       % see if we can find Y in I
  ! .                 % and eliminate any alternatives.
find( Y , I , G ) :-  %
  integer(G) ,        % enforce the contract that G must be bound
  G > 0 ,             % if we've not yet hit zero
  G1 is G-1 ,         % decrement G
  expand(I,I1) ,      % expand I
  find(Y,I1,G1)       % and recurse down
  .                   %
```

Note that the above **requires** the initial call to to `find/3` to have its third argument bound to an integer.

If, instead, you want your third argument to *return* the count, rather than defining a limit (and using a hard-coded limit instead), you can use a helper with an accumulator:

```
find( Y , I, G ) :-
  find(Y,I,1,G)
  .

find( Y , I , G , G ) :-
  G =< 50 ,              % if we've not yet exceeded the limit
  member(Y,I) ,          % see if we can find Y in I
  ! .                    % and eliminate alternatives
find( Y , I , T , G ) :- %
  T < 50 ,               % if we're below the limit
  T1 is T+1 ,            % increment the accumulator
  expand(I,I1) ,         % expand I
  find(Y,I1,T1,G)        % and recurse down.
  .                      % easy!
```

Or you can pass in the limit another argument and get the recursion count on success:

```
find( Y , I, N , G ) :-
  find(Y,I,N,1,G)
  .

find( Y , I , N , G , G ) :-
  G =< N ,
  member(Y,I) ,
  ! .
find( Y , I , N , T , G ) :-
  T < N ,
  T1 is T+1 ,
  expand(I,I1) ,
  find(Y,I1,N,T1,G)
  .
```

There's more than one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

from your pastebin, I get

```
find(Y,I,G) :- member(Y,I), G is 0.
find(Y,I,G) :- not(member(Y,I)), expand(I,O), find(Y,O,G1), G is G1+1.
find(Y,I,50) :- fail.
```

I would try

```
find(Y,I,0) :- member(Y,I).
find(Y,I,G) :- G < 50, not(member(Y,I)), expand(I,O), G1 is G+1, find(Y,O,G1).
```

Comment: I always get this error if I change those 2 lines `ERROR: </2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`. Does it maybe has somthing to do with the SWI-prolog interpreter I use?

Comment: This also results in this error: `ERROR: </2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your interpreter you can use

```
find(X,Y,50) :- fail
```

Comment: I use SWI-prolog. But this is somehow not working, I tried it before.

Comment: SWI-prolog has `fail` and `false` so probably it doesn't work because it fails buy go for the other definition (below or above). If you post more of the code and how you call it maybe i can tell you. For now i only can tell you to write N\==50 in all the others declarations

Comment: I added a link to my code and a explanation in my first post.